# How to rename a Testcase or Teststep using Groovy in SoapUi

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am re factoring large sets of tests in SoapUi. 
Is there a way to automate creation and renaming of test cases/test steps through Groovy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Groovy code within SoapUI using [SoapUI Groovy Console plugin](https://github.com/olensmar/soapui-groovy-console-plugin). This way, you can change any property you want programmatically (within API constraints of course).

As for technical details on how to solve your actual problem, I can only refer you to [this blog post](http://olensmar.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/a-groovy-console-for-soapui.html) and [SoapUI's javadoc](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/). Based on the blog post, you need to figure out what's given to you, and based on the API, you need to figure out how to achieve what you need.

In my case, I started with my project being bound as a `project` variable, and moved on from there.

Comment: This is definitely helpful. Is there a way to find some more information on this ? Like cloning test steps and assertions through the plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly not what you're looking for but I've had some success manually editing the test suite xml using find and replace in a text editor. You need to be careful and make sure to back up a copy.

Comment: Can this method be used to create TestSuite/testcase/teststeps too?

Comment: Yes if you where re using previously built things. I wouldn't advise writing them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is really not so much information in the question about what you really need to achieve, but given the little you provided, one way to go would be to directly modify the soapUI project XML file. I have done this with some success in the past. The last I used soapUI, it UI did not come with massive refactoring functionality.